# Python/Django : TypeError : __str__ returned non-string (type UUID)

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I created a Child model which have a `ForeignKey` instance 'parent' related to the Parent model. I wanted to associate a child to Post. For this, In my forms I created a `ModelChoiceField` for 'parent' field.  So to render this in my template, I make something as my below code.  When i running the code, it raising an error:

> TypeError : **str** returned non-string (type UUID).

I would appreciate helping me in fix this error.

Here's my code:

Models.py:

```
class Parent(models.Model):

    parent_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
    from1 = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    objects = ParentManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.parent_id

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("detail", kwargs={"id": self.parent_id})


class Child(models.Model):

    child_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, default=uuid.uuid4, related_name='childs' )
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True, unique=False)
    amount = models.IntegerField()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("accept_child", kwargs={"child_id": self.child_id})

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.amount

    def __str__(self):
        return self.amount
```

forms.py:

```
 class ChildForm(forms.ModelForm):

    parent = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset= Parent.objects.all(), label="Parent", widget=forms.RadioSelect(), initial=0)
    amount = forms.IntegerField(help_text='Place the child for a Parent')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(ChildForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['parent'].queryset = Parent.objects.all()

    class Meta:
        model = Child
        fields = ["amount"]
```

Template:

```
<td > {% for choice in form.parent.field.choices %} 
<li><input type="radio" name="{{ choice.parent }}" value="{{ choice.0 }}" />
<label for="">{{choice.1}}</label></li>
{% endfor %}</td>
```

Update-1:

views.py:

```
def live_bid_truck(request):

form = ChildForm(request.POST or None)

if  form.is_valid():
    child = form.save(commit=False)

    print(form.cleaned_data.get("amount"))
    child.user = request.user # YOU SET THE USER 
    child.parent = ?? # I DON'T HOW TO SET THE PARENT HERE, 


    child.save()


    print(child.parent.id)
```

Comment: you need to use `self.fields['parent'].queryset = Parent.objects.all()` in your `ChildForm`. Note the `()`.

Comment: Thanks. I missed parentheses. Now, I'm getting an error: __str__ returned non-string (type UUID) as i used UUID as primary key. May I know why i am getting this?

Comment: Use it as str(uuid field).

Comment: IMHO it's better to ask this in another question, to avoid pollution. Or you can change your original question.

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare Should i keep str(uuid field) in my Parent model?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This may help you:

Use following code if you want to write something in your primary key field table on the basis of primary key accepting from Front End.

```
import uuid
uuidField = uuid.UUID(uuidField)
```

And If you want to request to database and send that output to FrontEnd the use it as str(uuidField) otherwise it will not get serialize. and will give you error.

Change it as follow:

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.parent_id)
```

Comment: Where should i use this? As a new field in my parent model?

Comment: Still i getting the same error. What actually uuidField = uuid.UUID(uuidField) have a role here? Should i include it in somewhere in my code?

Comment: That is what when you need add some rows in uuid field's table as FrontEnd send it as str so for comparison purpose you need to change it in uuid.

Comment: Yes, bro. I have a question, How can i save the instance 'parent' in my views under ChildForm ? I updated the question with my views. Have a look at it in one minute.

Comment: In my page i'm getting the whole queryset in every row of the table. How can i seperate theses choices by row?